# Unity- Shortest route from one place to another

Tags: unity-game-engine

So I have been tasked with making an app using Unity to build a shortest route algorithm of a multi-floor building. 
I am completely new to unity and have no knowledge of the program.

I am hoping to get some pointers and some tips as to how I would approach this problem (make a 3D model, or make a 2D map of each floor, etc.)

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: This isn't really about Unity but rather a basic and conceptional question.

Comment: If YOU are tasked with writing the algorithm, Google Dijkstra's Algorithm or A* Pathfinding.

Answer (score 0):

What are you looking for is probably NavMesh Agents. It has visual parameters for general behaviour such as detection of obstacles, as well as scripts for the objects behaviour. I will link below the documentation and some videos which helped me to learn the concept:

- official youtube video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mP7ulMu5UkU)
- official documentation on the matter [here](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/navigation/navmesh-agent)
- youtube video about an RPG with AI movement [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S2mK6KFdv0I)

I think that is enough to grasp the idea, but if you have anything to ask, I will be here to help you